# How to represent JSONSchema of JSON which key names are in enum value?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I create my own JSON format file like this:

```
{
  "title": {
    "ja": "ドラえもん",
    "en": "Doraemon",
    "ko": "도라에몽",
    "de": #Any other languages...
  }
}
```

I want to create JSONSchema of this JSON, but how should I represent such kind of ("ja", "en", "ko", ...) free or enum value JSON keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "patternProperties" to specify that keys are of 2 letters, and that the value is a string, like this:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
        "^[a-z]{2}$": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "title"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use draft-06 or later you may want to try `propertyNames`, which allows you to specify a schema for the *names* rather than *values* of object properties.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-00#section-6.5.8